# Do you have references on preferred responses for information requests in conversation?

Tags: reference-request, questions

I am doing an analysis of specific predicates in complement clauses in conversation. In the language I am working with (but I suppose this could happen frequently), the predicate *'know'* happens much more frequently in the negative (e.g. *'I don't know that/if ...'*) than in the positive (*'I know that ...'*).

I think it makes sense because most of the occurrences of this predicate are responses to requests for information. If I were to follow my instinct: the 'negative' answer to a request for information like *"how much does it cost?"* is *"I don't know (how much it costs)"*. The positive answer is probably not *"I know (how much it costs)"* but rather the information requested.

Is there any work out there that explicitly states what are the preferred responses for information requests? I tried checking work by Tanya Stivers but could not find a point on the exact topic I was looking for (or I did not check the right work).